# tesseract Remove_Reference ambiguous symbol in project on visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, tesseract

I will describe my situation more in detail. I am building a system for the recognition of license plates, using C + + ,OpenCV ,Tesserect , but when I compile the code it is returned to me a stack of errors ambiguous references, so I inspected all lines of my code .
I searched this group for solutions and have tried several without success.

**Problems:**

```
error C2872 : ' Remove_Reference ' : ambiguous symbol File: tesscallback.h Line : 1011
error C2872 : ' Remove_Reference ' : ambiguous symbol File: tesscallback.h Line : 1030
error C2872 : ' Remove_Reference ' : ambiguous symbol File: tesscallback.h Line : 1061
error C2872 : ' Remove_Reference ' : ambiguous symbol File: tesscallback.h Line : 1105
error C2872 : ' Remove_Reference ' : ambiguous symbol File: tesscallback.h Line : 1136
error C2872 : ' Remove_Reference ' : ambiguous symbol File: tesscallback.h Line : 1179
error C2872 : ' Remove_Reference ' : ambiguous symbol File: tesscallback.h Line : 1208
```

**Software used:**

```
MS visual studio 2012
Path to visual studio : " C : \ Program Files ( x86 ) \ Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0 \ Common7 \ IDE \ devenv.exe "
OpenCV version: 2.4.8
OS: Windows 7 Home Premium , 64 -bit
Core i7
Tesseract version: tesseract - 2.3.02 - win32 - lib -include -dirs ( tested other versions )
Inguagem used : C + +11
```

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been in trouble for couple days with exactly the same problem (I am working on plate recognition project by using tesseract also) and I have just solved it. REMOVE "using namespaces XXX" CODE LINES FROM YOUR HEADER FILES(.h) (if causing an error in .h files tolerate them by using std::vector or cv::Mat etc) AND USE "using namespace XXX" CODE LINES IN YOUR SOURCE CODE(.cpp file).

I refered this link: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/456267-idataobject-ambiguous-symbol-error

and sorry about my ENGLISH :)

Answer (score 5):

The thing is that the latest C++ has a definition of `remove_reference` in [`std`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference) , and `tesscallback.h` contains another definition. When you use `using namespace std`, compiler will give an error due to redefinition.

You can either **delete all `using namespace std` and use `std::`** (recommended and explained [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)) or **uncomment all `definitions of remove_reference` in `tesscallback.h`**.

Answer (score 4):

I have solved the same problem by following method

```
// Specified by TR1 [4.7.2] Reference modifications.
// template <class T> struct remove_reference;
// template<typename T> struct remove_reference { typedef T type; };
// template<typename T> struct remove_reference<T&> { typedef T type; };
```